# Google Chrome debugger is working weird

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am currently testing 2nd example in [W3Schools Template Page](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_template.asp) and tried to log the value, weirdly different values are displayed in chrome debugger when I use F10 and continue button as shown in the gif below. Please let me know if anyone has any idea. Thank you.

It's displaying wrong when continuing without using F10

[Chrome Debugger Gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HhG37.gif)

In the code the text from the array is added after the console.log but somehow array value is added before the log. To test I also logged the item directly

```js
                var myArr = ["Audi", "BMW", "Ford", "Honda", "Jaguar", "Nissan"];
                function showContentArray() {
                    var temp, item, a, i;

                    //get the template element:
                    temp = document.getElementsByTagName("template")[0];

                    //get the DIV element from the template:
                    item = temp.content.querySelector("div");

                    //for each item in the array:
                    for (i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
                        debugger;

                        //Create a new node, based on the template:
                        a = document.importNode(item, true);
                        console.log(a);
                        console.log(document.importNode(item, true));

                        //Add data from the array:
                        a.textContent += myArr[i];

                        //append the new node wherever you like:
                        document.body.appendChild(a);
                    }
                }
```

```html
  <button onclick="showContentArray()">Show content Array</button>

  <template>
      <div class="templateClass">I like:</div>
  </template>
```

I inserted code here.

Note: I am using static html pages

Comment: The GIF is changing too quickly for me to see what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

You get the correct console logs if you single-step through the code, but if you click the continue button you see incorrect logging.

I suspect this is because the console is running asynchronously with the debugger. The code logs a DOM node, then immediately modifies the contents of the node. By the time the console actually displays the node that was logged, its contents have changed, so you see the updated contents in the log.

If you change it to `console.log(a.textContent)` then you're not logging a live object.

```js
var myArr = ["Audi", "BMW", "Ford", "Honda", "Jaguar", "Nissan"];

function showContentArray() {
  var temp, item, a, i;

  //get the template element:
  temp = document.getElementsByTagName("template")[0];

  //get the DIV element from the template:
  item = temp.content.querySelector("div");

  //for each item in the array:
  for (i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) {
    debugger;

    //Create a new node, based on the template:
    a = document.importNode(item, true);
    console.log(a.textContent);
    console.log(document.importNode(item, true));

    //Add data from the array:
    a.textContent += myArr[i];

    //append the new node wherever you like:
    document.body.appendChild(a);
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showContentArray()">Show content Array</button>

<template>
      <div class="templateClass">I like:</div>
  </template>
```

Comment: "You get the correct console logs if you single-step through the code, but if you click the continue button you see incorrect logging." yes.


Now I understand, Thank you..!!